# How to get shadows on the ground plane? (Noob)

Tags: light

I'm using Blender Internal. I have a ground plane set as receiving shadows, I have two light emitting planes, both have cast shadows on. I am using indirect lighting to utilize the effect of the light emitting planes. But I get no shadows cast on the ground plane, by the main object, a robot. How to get these shadows? Sorry for the noob question, I just suspect I'm missing some simple tick here or there, that will switch it on. :-)

Comment: In BI, the shadows may be achieved only by Spot lamps. in case of not turning on *Raytracing* option in *Shading* scroll (which is rather resources consuming)

Comment: Helpful. I have done some testing, and I figured I can use Area Light instead of Light Emission, but it gives a pretty hard raytraced shadow. An option would be to do a little bit Environment Light, say 0.1 this gives a nice soft shadow. And it seems Cycles would be a better option, only I already have all materials in BI. Will do some more testing later on today. Cheers.